# Does Python's open() read an unflushed buffer?

Tags: python, file-io, buffer

My knowledge of how file buffers work is fairly weak, so forgive the simple mindedness of this question. I have a piece of code in Python that waits for a file to appear, then reads it.

```
while 1:
    try:
        f = open('file.txt')
        f.close()
        print "Message received."
        break
    except:
        time.sleep(0.3)
```

Where `file.txt` is a file written by another program. However, I've a suspicion that Python is reading the file and then closing the handle before the file `file.txt` is completely written (that is, before I even call `close()` in the program that is writing the file). Should this even be possible?

If it is the case, is there a way I can detect (in the reading program listed above) whether or not the buffers have been flushed before I call `f.close()`?

Comment: In this case, no, because my goal in this little program is to check if the file exists, and is fully written. But would `f.read()` solve my problem? (the problem of unflushed buffers)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use a `while-loop` for this purpose. There is a better way, though the details depend on your OS.

Linux has [inotify](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inotify). You can write a simple [pyinotify](http://pyinotify.sourceforge.net) script to watch the directory and react to `IN_CLOSE_WRITE` events (which occur only *after* the file has been closed).

OSX ([FSEvents](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FSEvents)) and [Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3517460/is-there-anything-like-inotify-on-windows/3517475#3517475) have similar facilities.

Comment: Thanks, this was what I was looking for. I've used pyinotify to monitor for FS changes, but it didn't occur to me to use it for this very simple task.

Answer (score 1):

Python will not stop you from reading a file that another process has not completed writing.

If I'm waiting for a file from another process, I usually have that process write to a different file name.  Once that process has finished writing it closes and renames the file to the file name i'm expecting.  That way I don't get a partial file.

Answer (score 1):

To check whether a file exists, use `os.path.exists` or maybe `os.path.isfile` if you require it to be a "regular" file.

On Unix, a directory entry will be created when the file is opened for write/append.  But bytes written to a file will not actually show up there (from the point of view of a reader) until I/O is flushed.  There is no normal way of asking whether there is "pending" I/O on a file; at least not on Unix.

Answer (score 0):

In general Linux has no problem whatsoever with one process opening a file for read while another process has it open for writing. Think about doing things like `tail -f $SOME_FILE` to follow updates to a file in real time; that could not possibly work if attempting to open the file for reading had to block and wait until the writer closed the file.