# questions about implementing pyinotify instance to monitor directory

Tags: python, linux, events, loops, inotify

I have some basic questions about pyinotify that I can't seem to find the answers to elsewhere.

1) For a continuous directory monitor (and event processor) is it necessary to have a while( True ) loop or is the continuous event 'loop' handled by the notify watch and ended when I remove the watch?

2) What happens if files are pre-existing when the inotify instance is 'turned-on'?  Initially I just want to monitor for IN_CREATE but this won't handle pre-existing files.

3) Similar to #2, what happens if a file gets created while I'm in my event processor function? Will pyinotify cache it in its queue and process it when the 'loop' starts again, or will I lose this event?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- **is it necessary to have a while( True ) loop**

You'll need a `while-loop`, but it can be set up implicitly by calling the `notifier.loop` method:

```
    wm = pyinotify.WatchManager()
    mask = pyinotify.IN_CREATE
    notifier = pyinotify.Notifier(wm, MyProcessEvent(path))
    wdd = wm.add_watch(path, mask, rec=True, auto_add=True)
    notifier.loop()
```

If you wish to set up the `while-loop` yourself, you might start with this [source code](https://github.com/seb-m/pyinotify/blob/master/python3/pyinotify.py#L1377) from `notifier.loop`:

```
    while 1:
        try:
            notifier.process_events()
            # check_events is blocking
            if notifier.check_events():
                notifier.read_events()
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            # Stop monitoring if sigint is caught (Control-C).
            break
    notifier.stop()
```

To remove a watch of a particular file or directory, call `wm.rm_watch`.

- **What happens if files are pre-existing when the inotify instance is 'turned-on'?**

  No event is generated before `wm.add_watch` is called.
- **what happens if a file gets created while I'm in my event processor function?**

  The events are queued in a buffer of size
  `/proc/sys/fs/inotify/max_queued_events`. For example, on my system
  that number is

  ```
  % cat /proc/sys/fs/inotify/max_queued_events
  16384
  ```

  If the filesystem generates enough events to fill up the buffer while
  you are processing a prior event, then you get a `IN_Q_OVERFLOW`
  event.

  See the comment in [blucz's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3517567/190597).

Comment: so the only time I need to account for files that pyinotify won't find is when the program starts and the directory (potentially) has files already.  I will need a directory iterator function to manually handle these, then intro into the pyinotify instance....

Comment: @unutbu - alternatively I found that I can implement a asyncore.loop() with pyinotify to create the infinite while loop, docs found here: https://github.com/seb-m/pyinotify/blob/master/python2/examples/tutorial_asyncnotifier.py

Comment: Oh! I hadn't known about that. Thanks for sharing.

Comment: `notifier`, the instance of `pyinotify.Notifier` has a method `loop` that takes care of the looping so you don't have to write a `while True: …`. See [the example here.](https://github.com/seb-m/pyinotify/blob/master/python2/examples/loop.py)