# PHP folder watching on windows

Tags: php, filesystemwatcher

I am writing a simple PHP script to watch a folder and its subfolders for any changes (new files, modifications, deletions) and then perform an action.

I will run this script from the commandline on windows using `php -f script.php`.

I have been search for a way to watch folders on windows that has PHP bindings. Something like inotify or gamin for windows would be nice.

The answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3517460/is-there-anything-like-inotify-on-windows) mentions `FindFirstChangeNotification`, but I couldn't find any PHP bindings for it.

Are there any libraries/software for folder/filesystem watching on windows with PHP bindings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up just writing a simple function using the `RecursiveDirectoryIterator` that is called in an infinit loop.

All I have to do is check the last modified time of the file or a folder and return true or false.

This isn't a very exact approach, but it serves my purposes well. Sitting in the back ground, the script uses about 12MB of ram.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [inotify_add_watch](http://php.net/manual/en/function.inotify-init.php) PHP function to get notification of any changes (new files, modifications, deletions) in specified directory. It works the same way as [FileSystemWatcher](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher(v=vs.110).aspx) on Windows.

Comment: It doesn't look like this extension is available on Windows, though: as per the [doc](https://www.php.net/manual/en/inotify.requirements.php): "*This extension requires Linux 2.6.13 or newer, and a recent libC.*".

Answer (score -1):

If you have Ruby installed on your server you can use [`watchr gem`](https://github.com/mynyml/watchr)

What it does is very simple, upon fire/directory change it executes a script defined by you which is exactly what you're trying to do.

Here is an example file `autotest.rb`:

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby

# Match all PHP files in your project directory
watch("<PROJECT_DIR_PATH>/(.*).<FILE_EXTENSION_PHP>") do |match|
  run_test %{<PROJECT_DIR_PATH>/Tests/#{match[1]}Test.php}
end

# Match all files in your Tests directory
watch("<PROJECT_DIR_PATH>/Tests/.*Test.php") do |match|
  run_test match[0]
end

# Run test if there are matches
def run_test(file)
  unless File.exist?(file)
    puts "#{file} does not exist"
    return
  end

  puts "Running #{file}"
  result = `phpunit #{file}`
  puts result
end
```

So this wil match all PHP or any other extension files and run RegEx against the name of the file and if there is a match like /Project/Tests/ClassNameTest.php it will run the test otherwise just terminate with massage. For convenience this could be set to send emails upon errors to predefined list emails.