# Detect the modification of a file

Tags: php, apache

Is it possible to detect the modification of a file in PHP?

Particularly I'm looking for when the file is updated, but create/save/ etc. would be nice.

Ultimately, I'm hoping to trigger some sort of action on my server for sending an email alert or something similar when a file is updated.

Answer (score 1):

[`filemtime`](https://www.php.net/filemtime) should do what you want

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question. `filemtime` will allow you to see the modified time of a file, but not "detect" a new modification / new file. You'd need to tie it in with something like a cron job.

Comment: Thanks this was helpful. Browsing through the user contributed notes for the filemtime func, I found something I may be able to run on a cron to get what I want.

Comment: @JonStirling For every solution (`filemtime`, or `md5_file()`) you need to keep a previous state to detect the changes.

Comment: @KingCrunch Not really. With `filemtime` and When using cron you know how often it runs, as such you would be looking for changes made within the difference of time between the start of 2 runs. No need to store anything.

Comment: @JonStirling Would tell it an "implicit state" ;), but right, this way you need a storage to track the latest change.

Comment: @KingCrunch Aye. But, if you were commenting on my first comment, when I said detect I meant it in the context of the OP, as in `filemtime` (or PHP for that matter) won't actively monitor the file system for changes, thus won't work for triggers, which is what the OP was about.

Comment: Yeah, I'm sorry, I should have been more clear initially. Was hoping for the active detection of the modification, instead of having to check for modification manually via cron or something. Appreciate all the help!

Answer (score 1):

For a cron-job-less approach, you can have a look at [`ext/inotify`](http://php.net/book.inotify). There you register a callback and put the whole process into a read-loop, that always triggers the callback, if an event (for example `IN_CLOSE_WRITE`) occurs.

Answer (score 0):

See [`filemtime`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filemtime.php). There are similar functions to check the creation time etc.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check wether the file was changed, you could record the md5 hash of the files:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.md5-file.php

Here is the same question: [PHP folder watching on windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9271104/php-folder-watching-on-windows)

With ruby, python or other languages, you could register a watcher on the filesystem, so you have a push and no information pull. But afaik is this not possible with PHP.

Comment: Yeah, I see what you're saying and was hoping for more of a push method myself. Appreciate the help though, I'll take a look at maybe setting up a python script.