# PHP proc_open on windows

Tags: php, windows

I have created a process using `proc-open` but under windows the [stream-select](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stream-select.php) does not work. What I am trying to achieve is to read from both *stdout* and *stderr*, whilst in addition writing to *stdin* and ensure that the output can be matched up with the inputs. Is there a workaround for windows to overcome this deficiency?

Comment: I think the only thing you can do is to set your pipes in non-blocking mode and check them manually, unfortunately.

Comment: @netcoder - I have tried this. `stream_set_blocking` returns false :-(

Comment: stderr and stdout cannot be set to non blocking.

What are you trying to achieve exactly? Have some code? select may not be necessary here.

Comment: Can you distinguish messages printed to `stderr` from messages printed to `stdout` (by using some sort of regexp for example)?

Comment: @galymzhan - The two streams are diffenent in the fact that they come from two different file descriptors. Also, sometimes there is nothing to be read.

Comment: @EdHeal I wanted to suggest to redirect `stderr` to `stdout`, so you'll have to worry about `stdout` only. Not sure how to implement non-blocking access, though

Comment: @galymzhan - but either way the output might not be av available. Sort of want the PHP to act as expect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not very detailed on what is not working for you with stream-select on Windows. However, this is a working example on how to use stream-select. I just ran this successfully with PHP 5.4 on Windows XP.

**Edit:** Uhhmmm.. Seems like it was non-working after all... Sry, testing some more here.. :)

**Edit again:**

So, I did some more experimenting on this, but unsuccessfully.

Maybe you should just let the processes speak TCP/UDP/IP to each other?

Another way forward (if you still want to use stdout/stdin/stderr in your process) might be to use proc_open with file handlers, so your process is writing to files, and then use something similar to unix' inotify, loading this stuff with the PHP DOTNET class: [Is there anything like inotify on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3517460/is-there-anything-like-inotify-on-windows) to detect changes to the files...? Just an idea...

Or maybe change to a unix-like os? ;) Ok, that's it for me tonight. Good night

Comment: `stream_select` in your example seems useless. It just reads from `stdout` and `stderr` pipes without actually looking into what is returned in `$read_streams`. This could block if child process is busy (or child wrote into `stderr` when you're waiting data on `stdout`)

Comment: @AlfredGodoy - The problem is that windows `select` does not work. But unix/linux it seems to work. Sorry for the effort for code that does not work.

Comment: @AlfredGodoy - You get the bounty for the effort. Should not go to waste.

Comment: Thnx :) Added some more ideas on this in the answer.

Comment: @AlfredGodoy - I will put you on my list of kind people.

Comment: @AlfredGodoy -Ask me a question and I will try to give you an  answer

Answer (score 1):

adding bypass_shell worked for me

```
$proc=proc_open($cmd,
        array(
            0=>array('pipe', 'r'), //stdin
            1=>array('pipe', 'w'), //stdout
            2=>array('pipe', 'w')  //stderr
            ),
        $pipes,
        $dir,
        null,
        array('bypass_shell'=>true)
    );
```