# Any Windows GUI components that can bind to display an open file's contents as updated?

Tags: windows, user-interface, file-io, clr

Is it possible to directly bind a Windows GUI component (like a RichTextBox) to display (read-only) the contents of a file that is being appended by another process?  I.e., so if something new is written to the file the component would display that new content?

What's the most *straightforward* way of doing it in C++/C#/CLR?  Given that this is not an uncommon task I'm wondering if there is something easier than setting up a FileSystemWatcher and then on callback doing all the plumbing and synchronizing between the file and the GUI component's buffer.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/721714/notification-when-a-file-changes

Comment: also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3517460/is-there-anything-like-inotify-on-windows

Comment: Yes, FileSystemWatcher is part of the kludge I had suggested, and hoped to avoid.  I.e., I'm expecting and asking whether there are already components that can be bound to an open file so I don't have to run a Watcher and plumb the changes into the component.

Answer (score 1):

Using System.IO.FileSystemWatcher you can get events telling you when the file is updated, then you re-read the file and update your control.

Comment: That's the kludgy approach I described in my second paragraph.  Unless there is a trivial way to sync a control to the last _n_ lines of a file.

Comment: Fair enough, it was not very clear what you meant by filesystem monitor.