# How to wait until a file is created in C

Tags: c

How can I stop the execution of a thread until a file is created ?
I would like to avoid doing it in a busy loop, and use something with a behavior similar to select(). Is something like this possible?
I only found ways to check if a file exists at a given time.

Comment: Punch "file alteration monitor" into your favorite search engine.

Comment: You can't do this in pure C. If you're on a Linux system, have a look at `inotify`.

Comment: ... created by what/how?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz seems that I wasn't punching the right keywords in my favorite search engine, the results with "file alteration monitor" is indeed much more interesting than what I found previously, thanks for your comment!

Comment: Thank you @EOF I think this is what I was looking for

Comment: @where_is_tftp : created by another thread or process, on a linux system

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are probably looking for [`inotify(7)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/inotify.7.html). At the botton of the man page linked, there's example showing how to monitor for various events.

Comment: There are [APIs with similar features (but completely different names and functions) for Windows and OSX](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3517567/364696).

Comment: @usr: thank you, I think this is what I was looking for. More precisely, watching the directory that will contain the file for the IN_CREATE event and then checking if the file is there should work fine!