# Python Inotify for a list of folders

Tags: python, bash, inotify, inotifywait

I am looking for a way to check a list of document roots of 5 domains to inotify directory watch.

For a single folder it is working like this

`DIRECTORY_TO_WATCH = "/home/serveradmin/"`

I have a list of folders which needs to be checked recursively for my server.

I just started learning python and have some hands on experience in C language. Just starting learning developments.

Is there anyone who can help me on this? I need to have a recursive inotify watch on 5 folders mentioned in a file named /tmp/folderlist.txt

IS there any similar code available anywhere I can refer?

Answer (score 1):

install `inotify-tools`:

```
sudo apt-get install inotify-tools
```

and try something like:

```
inotifywait = ['inotifywait',
               '--recursive',
               '--quiet',
               '--monitor', ## '--timeout', '1',
               '--event',
               'CREATE',
               '--format', '%f']

from subprocess import PIPE, Popen
p = Popen(inotifywait + paths, stdout=PIPE)
for line in iter(p.stdout.readline, ''):
    print(line)
```

For macosx you can get similar results using `fswatch`:

```
if sys.platform == 'darwin':
    inotifywait = ['fswatch', '--event', 'Created']
```

For windows see : [Is there anything like inotify on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3517460/is-there-anything-like-inotify-on-windows)

Answer (score 0):

So you want to create a list of the folders then do a for a statement to check if they exist.

So do

```
import os
list = ['folder1', 'folder2', 'folder3', 'folder4', 'folder5']
for i in list:
    print("\nDoes", list[i], "exsist?", os.path.exists("/home/serveradmin/" + list[i]))
```

Replace the items in list with the correct folder names!

Good luck!

Comment: The OP wants to use inotify so that they can be notified when a directory is changed. They do not want to check if a directory exists

Comment: Yes he is correct. This needs to be passed to inotify to keep an eye on file changes recursively

Comment: Any other options available for this ? also do any one know which is the most valid / useful c programming to python convertors ? Is there any thing like that

Comment: @Sumesh did you get it working? If so please mark my answer as correct so people in the future can fix this issue!

Answer (score 0):

This is the sample code I have started working. I need to replace "DIRECTORY_TO_WATCH" to a list of folders which I will add in a file. So basically it will be a  list of folders specified in a txt file so that I can just keep adding future folders in that file and no need to add the core code every time.

```
import time
from watchdog.observers import Observer
from watchdog.events import FileSystemEventHandler

class Watcher:
    DIRECTORY_TO_WATCH = "/path/to/my/directory"

    def __init__(self):
        self.observer = Observer()

    def run(self):
        event_handler = Handler()
        self.observer.schedule(event_handler, self.DIRECTORY_TO_WATCH, recursive=True)
        self.observer.start()
        try:
            while True:
                time.sleep(5)
        except:
            self.observer.stop()
            print "Error"
```