# Besides monitoring all directories, how to know there's a new file saved n

Tags: r, filesystems

I'm working with a machine which treats data from different sources and will save the results to the directory accordingly. My task is to find the latest result and follow up with data manipulation in R.

Since we can't anticipate which source the new data will come, so, it seems to me the result will go randomly, and I have no control about where the results be saved.

How can I know the location the new file goes? Must I keep a large File System myself besides the system?

Comment: Yes, I need a R answer, so I can move on with R. Thanks for adding it.

Comment: If you are on Linux you could use inotifywait to launch an R script when the directory of interest changes. If on Windows see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3517460/is-there-anything-like-inotify-on-windows

Answer (score 2):

Try this.

1. Create a `test` directory and add some text file named `a.txt` in it.
2. Run `initial = list.files("~/test/", recursive = TRUE)` to list all files in `test`.
3. Add another file named `b.txt` to simulate creation of a file
4. Run `current = list.files("~/test/", recursive = TRUE)` again to list the files in `test`
5. Then you can compare `current` with `initial`

```
current[!current %in% initial]
#[1] "b.txt"
```

Comment: Isn't this what they were trying to avoid? "Must I keep a large File System myself besides the system?" But I don't know of any other OS-level API to trigger actions on file creation.

Comment: I am looking for R functions/packages for NTFS or FAT